# Put PageContet in ASP.NET UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

What problems might be caused if I put all page contents in an ASP.NET UpdatePanel?
I mean something like this in the masterpage:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder  ID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat=server ID="asdasd" ChildrenAsTriggers=true>
        <ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about basically having all navigation throughout your entire site being done within an UpdatePanel? Well, for a start, that will make it impossible for anyone to bookmark anything, it will probably render your site unable to be indexed by search engines, and will just generally be confusing for the use.

The whole point of a partial postback is that it is, well, **partial**. Having everything within an UpdatePanel will get you all of the disadvantages and none of the advantages.